# Tkinter Toplevel width and height not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code, when the method is run the Toplevel window displays the correct title and contents, but remains it's tiny default size. Am I doing something stupidly and obviously wrong here?

```
def new_game(self):
    self.top = tk.Toplevel(width=300, height=200)
    self.top.title("New Game Settings")
    title_msg = tk.Message(self.top, text="Which players do you wish to be controlled by the AI?")
    msg_ai_1 = tk.Message(self.top, text="Player 1")
    msg_ai_2 = tk.Message(self.top, text="Player 2")
    title_msg.pack()
    msg_ai_1.pack()
    msg_ai_2.pack()

    self.confirm_button = tk.Button(self.top, text="Okay", command=self.top.destroy)
    self.confirm_button.pack()
```

Answer (score 6):

Tk() and Toplevel() geometry can be set by `self.top.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (300, 200, 250, 125))`. First two numbers represent dimensions of window. Third and fourth number say, where the window will appear.

Comment: I confirmed that this works. It's documented here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
self.secondWin.wm_geometry("1000x1000")
```